# Can't change the value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to programming and javascript and am having trouble changing a value in a one of my arrays throught its index. The rest of the code works fine but I can't seem to access my faces[] through its index, while in another array it works fine.

```
f1 = 0;
f2 = 0;
f3 = 0;
f4 = 0;
f5 = 0;
f6 = 0;
faces = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6];

//loop through a single throw with 5 dies
for(var i = 0; i < dice.length; i++){
    var die = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

    //if hold is true skip the corresponding iteration
    if(hold1 == true && i===0){
        alert("holding: " + held[0]);//shows the value of the die that's being held
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            faces[i] = 5;//doesn't add anything
            faces[2] = 5; //nor does this
            faces[1]++; //or this
            f1 = 3; //this works however
        }
        alert("faces are: " + f1 + ", " + f2 + ", " + f3 + ", " + f4 + ", " + f5 + ", " + f6);
        continue; 
    }
//rest of code
```

The alert is to check if the values change and it returns 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 since only assigning it to the variables in the index directly seems to work.

Comment: why not use the array directly?

Comment: Your inner loop shouldn't use the same "i" variable as your outer loop. Change the variable name. Also, the inner condition, are you sure it is correct? `hold1 == true && i == 0` that looks suspiciously wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not change the value of `fx` as they are simple datatypes (int), they are `called by value`. Simple types are not objects, which can be `called by  reference`. See this question: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

```js
f1 = 0;
f2 = 0;
f3 = 0;
f4 = 0;
f5 = 0;
f6 = 0;
faces = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6];

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
  faces[i] = faces[i] + 5;//doesn't add anything
  faces[2] = faces[2] + 5; //nor does this
  faces[1] = faces[1]++; //or this
  f1 = 3; //this works however
}
console.log("faces are: " + f1 + ", " + f2 + ", " + f3 + ", " + f4 + ", " + f5 + ", " + f6);
console.log("faces are:" , faces);
```

Comment: @GomuGomu you are losing reference to your f-named variables when you set them via `faces[1] = <some value>`. This now means that indexed item no longer points to `f1`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code is expecting the variables to be updated when you update the `faces` at an array index, but `faces[1] = 5` assigns the value 5 to `faces[1]`, replacing the value (`0`) initially copied from `f1`. Try again, using the indexes only, but this time change your alert to:

```
alert("faces are: " + faces.join(','));
```

Also, as @StephenQuan points out, you need to use a different index variable for the inner loop

Comment: How about "replacing the value (0) copied from `f1` during array initialization "?

Comment: Thanks @Traktor53, that was an error on my part. This is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

See the section on [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). You are using `var i` in the inner loop as well as the outer loop. Change that and see if it helps the flow. Also I would suggest if possible using `let` instead of `var` if you are using ECMA 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing a reference to an object into the array. when you are first initializing the array.

Inside the loop you are executing

```
faces[i] = 5
```

you are replacing the reference to object f1 to value 5.

Please try the following.

```
faces = [{value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}];

faces[i].value = 5;

alert("faces are: " + face[0].value+ ", " + face[1].value+ ", " + face[2].value+ ", " + face[3].value+ ", " + face[4].value+ ", " + face[5].value);
```

Comment: The array is initialized with values of type "number" copied from variables `f1` through `f6` which are all zeroes.